# SSMS - Create linked server using JDBC

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

Is it possible to crate a linked server to another MSSQL server using JDBC? I don't see any options for JDBC in the Providers list, though I have downloaded the latest JDBC driver from Micorsoft. I have not found anything on the internet that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linked Server always uses OleDb.  It can't use JDBC.

Comment: Is there a method to access data from the MSSQL databse through the JDBC and use it in a stored procedure?

Comment: Why JDBC?  What’s the scenario?

Comment: One of our software vendors has the database in the cloud. They have JDBC and Citrix connections to it. I am attempting to find a way to link to that database so I can create some custom reports for our company dashboard.

Comment: So the target is not a SQL Server?

Comment: The target is a SQL Server.

Comment: Then you can use any driver.  There is nothing the JDBC driver can do that the OleDb, ODBC, or ADO.NET driver can’t.